# Set parameter to None if out of range in Pydantic

Tags: python, pydantic

He we would like to set value to None if it is out of range. Something similar to the code below (the code below is just example of an approach not actual code that supposed to work). We could not figure it out how to do it.

```
class FooClass(BaseModel):
    foo_val: Optional[Annotated[float, Field(ge=-90, le=90)]] = None

    @field_validator('foo_val')
    @classmethod
    def check_foo_val(cls, v: float, *, values, field, config):
        field_info = cls.__fields__[field].field_info
        if v < field_info.ge or v > field_info.le:
            return None
```

Comment: Did you mean `@field_validator('foo_val')`?

Comment: What exactly "does not work"?

Comment: @PawełRubin yes, thanks

This was just example of an approach, not actual implementation. Main thing would be to access ge, le,... inside validator which I think was possible in the V1.

We could define intervals somewhere else and just use that in validation method, but this would not be in the Pydantic spirit.

Comment: "We could not figure it out how to do it." What happens when you try your approach, and how is that different from the expectation?

Answer (score 0):

```
class FooClass(BaseModel):
    foo_val: Annotated[Optional[float], Field(ge=-90, le=90)] = None

    @field_validator('foo_val', mode="before")
    @classmethod
    def check_foo_val(cls, v: Optional[float], info: ValidationInfo):
        if v is not None:
            try:
                val = float(v)
            except ValueError:
                return v    # If input value is incompatible with float - just let
                            # Pydantic validate it and raise ValidationError
            
            for meta in cls.model_fields[info.field_name].metadata:
                if isinstance(meta, Ge) and val < meta.ge:
                    return None
                if isinstance(meta, Le) and val > meta.le:
                    return None
        return v
```